# Do we have right margin property in JSPDF?

Tags: javascript, jspdf

Do we have right margin property in JSPDF? It is not working in my case. The left botto top properties are working, it is only right margin that does not work.

```
    var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
    //var pdf = new jsPDF();

    source = $('#PDFContent').html();

    specialElementHandlers = {
        // element with id of "bypass" - jQuery style selector
        '#bypassme' : function(element, renderer) {
            // true = "handled elsewhere, bypass text extraction"
            return true
        }
    };

    margins = {
        top : 5,
        right: 10,
        bottom : 60,
        left : 10,
        width : 700
    };

    pdf.fromHTML(source, // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
    margins.left, // x coord
    margins.top, { // y coord
        'width' : margins.width, // max width of content on PDF
        'elementHandlers' : specialElementHandlers
    },

    function(dispose) {
        // dispose: object with X, Y of the last line add to the PDF 
        //          this allow the insertion of new lines after html
        headerFooterFormatting(pdf, pdf.internal.getNumberOfPages());
        pdf.save('Test.pdf');
    }, margins);
```

Comment: @Soman have u found your answer? I'm also struggling in this issue.

Comment: @Haris, no we dont have right margin property.